# How timers are executed in c#

Tags: c#

I was working with timers in c# and the curiosity of how they could be implemeted rised up. How the timer is executed, is in the calling thread? Does the thread receive like some kind of signal and the task performed by the timer is an signal handler? I am trying to understad how a thread that is executing something jumps to the code of a timer when the timer elapsed.

Comment: It depends on the timer. There are several and they work differently. Threads don’t jump anywhere, a timer that’s in the UI thread sends a message that’s handled in the message queue when the thread is ready to handle them.

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/timer.cs,051a39d380760b26 ;)

Comment: This is buried deep inside the OS, CLR or framework library, depending on what kind of timer you use.  Proper mental image is the core ability of a thread to use Sleep().  That takes only a single thread to service many timers.  It works the same way you use your wrist-watch, you only worry when your next appointment is due.  Your day-planner tells you when to look for the next one.  When the sleep completes it activates a threadpool thread (for asynchronous timers) and delivers a message (for synchronous ones) for any timers with the same due time.

Comment: I was doing some testing and there is something I dont understand. I created a small basic scheduler which only use system.threading.timer. what is interesting is that I set a task to run every 15s and then call Thread.Sleep(90000). but even if the thread is sleeping the task runs. The task performs only a console.writeline.